# Is the setInterval() an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

I am making a `XMLHttpRequest` every second to a server, the server will respond with new messages. To call the `XMLHttpRequest` every second I use the `setInterval()` function inside of a `SharedWorker`.

However, since I am making a request every second, I would like to know if `setInterval()` is asynchronous or not?

For example, if one `XMLHttpRequest` request took 3 seconds to finish "due to a delay", will I have 3  requests going at the same time or will `setInterval()` wait until the first request completes before it waits 1 second and send another request?

Here is my code

```
function checkQueue(url)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
}


function reqListener ()
{
    var queue = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    notifyAllPorts(queue);
    console.log(this.responseText);
}


setInterval(
    function() {
        checkQueue('/add-ons/icws/push.php') 
    }
, 1000);
```

Comment: It is asynchronous, but you won't  have 3 requests going at the same time, since the function interval is 1 sec. The provided function will execute every second, no matter what.

Comment: @MinusFour then I will have at least 2 going at the same time. If the server take 10 seconds to respond then request will keep coming. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: You could do it with a promise, I can provide an answer for that if the question is how to interval a promise.

Comment: @MinusFour They *could* be requests that take 'significant time'..

Comment: `setInterval` tries it's best to run at "n * duration" intervals.. but that is irrelevant to the core misunderstanding: "will setInterval() wait until the first request completes?" No, not as envisioned. The shown XHR code started from the `setInterval` is *asynchronous* and will 'finish almost immediately'; thus it isn't even relevant if setInterval waits (because the *asynchronous code already finished running*) or how it schedules itself for the next timeout.

Comment: Well setInterval can be delayed if CPU gets locked down before the next interval happens, so it's true, it tries its best to run at n intervals.

Comment: @MinusFour I am not sure what promise delivers but I think that is what am I looking for as in my case there is no point of making a new request if there is another pending. I want to call a function when it comes back, wait 1 second then call it again. Please provide an answer with a promise as it sound like what I am looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out, it won't wait until the request is done. Here's a way to interval a promise:

```
 function checkQueue(url, cb) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.addEventListener("loadend", cb);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
     xhr.open('GET', url, true);
     xhr.send();
 }

function reqListener ()
{
    var queue = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    notifyAllPorts(queue);
    console.log(this.responseText);
}

 var promise = Promise.resolve(true);

 setInterval(function () {
     promise = promise.then(function () {
         return new Promise(function (resolve) {
             checkQueue(yourUrlHere, resolve);
         });
     });
 }, 1000);
```

It will keep on adding requests to do every second, but it will delay itself if it goes over 1 second.

Comment: to make sure I am following you here. So if a request takes 10 second, will it create a queue with requests and once one is done it starts running the requests that are in the queue until it is cough up?

Comment: If a request takes 10 second, this would have queued up 8-9 requests to be done, but will only keep firing after the last finished. In other words, in an hour, it will queue up 3600 petitions. If the petitions all last 1 second, then all 3600 petitions will be done. If a petition takes more than 1 second, it will delay the next petition in the queue, until it's done, leading to less than 3600 petitions.

Comment: I tweeked your code a little as I am experiansing an issue where this code generated a new TCP connection per second. it does not reuse an open TCP connection. Please take a look at another question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505128/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-reuse-a-tcp-connection   thank you for you help :)

Comment: Can someone explain line number 3 and the promise inside setInterval handler?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll run into trouble. `setInterval` will go off like clockwork, irrespective of the state of your requests.

You're better-off starting a one hit timer using `setTimeout` at the completion of every request... so:

```
function checkQueue(url)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
}


function reqListener ()
{
    var queue = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    notifyAllPorts(queue);
    console.log(this.responseText);
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            checkQueue('/add-ons/icws/push.php') 
        }, 1000);
}


checkQueue('/add-ons/icws/push.php')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. So what will you code exactly do? how does it guarantee that a request will start only of one is completed?

Comment: ...because we only start a one-time timer once we are sure that the previous request is complete (i.e. after the `load` event of XMLHttpRequest... your callback is called therefore the request is done). This means that once the previous request is **finished**, then we wait for a second before restarting. Exactly what you wanted, no?

Comment: I see. So this code will ensure that no request is triggers unless the existing one is completed. Will this code reconnect if the connection between the server and the worker drops?

Comment: @MikeA No. If you want a robust means of ensuring that the show *always* rolls on (even if there's an error) you should also be listening to the `"error"` and `"abort"` events that `XMLHttpRequest` can emit, and deal with them accordingly. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for more information.

Comment: So should I add `xhr.addEventListener("error", reqListener);` and `xhr.addEventListener("abort", reqListener);` to my `checkQueue` function to establish the reconnect if a connection drops?

Comment: Probably not, as they won't have any  `responseText` as they represent an error situation. I'd suggest making another event handler function that is used for these **failure** cases. I believe your question is answered and now appears to be turning into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). If you have more questions that don't relate directly to your initial question, I would suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` simply queues the code to run once the current call stack is finished executing. This can be useful for some things.

So yes, it's asynchronous in that it breaks the synchronous flow, but it's not actually going to execute concurrently/on a separate thread. If your goal is background processing, have a look at webworkers.

So regardless of how much time server takes it will request every second as per your code is set for 1000

Comment: Does this mean `setTimeout` will execute a function 1 second after the function finishs, vs `setInterval` will execute regardless of the function's result?

Comment: It will execute regardless of the function's result. If you don't call: clearInterval() it won't stop, it will start again and again.

Answer (score -1):

yes the setInterval & setTimeout are asyncronous, but you not do a push, you do a pull, if you want a push request read about of web sockets

Comment: I can't use websockets in my case because I do not use frames. my site is reloaded all the time.