# How to make XMLHttpRequest reuse a TCP connection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, tcp, xmlhttprequest

I have Apache running on Windows 7 Pro. I installed Apache using XAMPP bundle.

I need to call an API once every second. To do that, I created a SharedWorker who calls the API every second using `XMLHttpRequest`

However, I am running into an issue where the web server Apache hits it's max TCP connection allowed. Of course I can increase the allowed TCP connections on the server, but that does not solve my problem it only patches it until the server gets busy and overloaded.

After troubleshooting the TCP problem, it become clear to me that the `XMLHttpRequest` is not reusing an existing TCP connection. It opens a new TCP connection with every request/every second. I expect to have 1 TCP connection to be utilized to handle my `XMLHttpRequest` connection.

While I was the only user is connection to the website on the server, I launched `TCPView` on the web server to watch the tcp connections. I started out with 30 TCP connection with a state of `TIME_WAIT`. Every second later, one more connection was created until it reached about 122-130 and then it stopped. Now the server seems to be recycling the connections every 60 seconds, but still generating a new TCP connection for every `XMLHttpRequest` every second.

I also understand that each time a page is loaded the client/browser could create multiple TCP connection for various of reasons. But, I am expecting to have 1 TCP connection to handle my `XMLHttpRequest` and resuse that connection over and over.

I know some may suggest using `WebSockets` or `Server-Sent-Events`, but in my case I can't. I must keep my ShardWorker implementation.

**Question**

What can I do to make the `XMLHttpRequest` reuse of an open TCP connection?

Below is my ShardWorker implementation i.e. `worker.js`

```
var clients = new Array();
var xhr = null;
//runs only when a new connection starts
onconnect = function(event) {

    var port = event.ports[0];
    clients.push(port);
    port.start();

    //implement a channel for a communication between the connecter and the SharedWorker
    port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) { 
            replyToClientMessage(event, port);
        } , false
    );
}

//reply to any message sent to the SharedWorker with the same message but add the phrase "SharedWorker Said: " to it
replyToClientMessage = function (event, port) {
    port.postMessage("Worker Replied With: " + event.data);
}


//check all open clients and post a message to each
 function notifyAllPorts(msg){

    var len = clients.length;
    var port;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        port = clients[i];
        port.postMessage(msg);
    }
}


 function checkQueue(cb) {
     //create a new XMLHttpRequest only once
    if (xhr == null) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("loadend", cb);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", handlerMessageReceived);
    }

    xhr.open('GET', '/add-ons/icws/push.php', true);
    xhr.send();
 }

//handler a sucessfull request
function handlerMessageReceived()
{
    var queue = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    notifyAllPorts(queue);
}



 var promise = Promise.resolve(true);

 setInterval(function () {
     promise = promise.then(function () {
         return new Promise(function (resolve) {
             checkQueue(resolve);
         });
     });
 }, 1000);
```

Here is how I put Sharedworker to work

```
    //establish connection to the shared worker
    var worker = new SharedWorker("/add-ons/icws/js/worker.js" );
    //listen for a message send from the worker
    worker.port.addEventListener("message",
        function(event) {
            console.log(event.data);
            processServerData(event.data);
        }
        , false
    );

    worker.onerror = function(event){
        console.log(event);
    };

    //start the connection to the shared worker
    worker.port.start();
```

Comment: Well, you can't really reuse it, HTTP is stateless. You open a connection, send a petition, the server responds, the connection is closed. And since connections aren't just closed like that ([time_wait purpose here](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html#purpose)), the more connections you get the worse it gets.

Comment: @MinusFour I am glad for your help. Does this mean I should somehow force the connection to close with every request or there is nothing I can do about this?

Comment: I don't think there's someting you could about this, besides using a protocol that keeps the connection open like HTTP websockets or reducing the time wait delay considerably which doesn't look very safe to me. What's the purpose of hitting the API once every second?

Comment: The purpose of reading the API every second is to I read new messaged from the server and update a local cache file then send back the cache value to the client.

Comment: I tried to add this to my code but the connection still stay on time_wait `xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');`

Comment: But are you monitoring your Apache connections pool? Use `mod_status` for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89313/discussion-between-mike-a-and-minusfour).